# How can I apply zoom in/out filter on specific frame in a video using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, zoom

I want to apply a zoom filter on a specific frame of a video using FFmpeg.

For example, I want to make a slideshow of 5 images, and each image will take 4-5 seconds for slide. In this video I want to apply a zoom in/out effect on each image. So, I want to apply this effect when a particular image stays still for 4-5 seconds.

I want to see a result similar to the first two slides in [this demonstration of the Ken Burns effect](https://youtu.be/nNTiyRDhlRY).

Comment: So you just want one frame to be zoomed in, for the fraction of a second? Or do you want the frame to freeze for a while?

Comment: yes, i want to zoom in one particular frame of a video for fraction of a second. @slhck

Comment: Q is unclear. Do you want zooming animation or only a zoomed version of one frame. Edit your Q with a more elaborate description.

Comment: i want zooming animation. and also I've edited my description. @Gyan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Generate video with zoom and image movement from one still image?](https://superuser.com/questions/1238725/how-to-generate-video-with-zoom-and-image-movement-from-one-still-image)

Comment: See duplicate question.